# c program char and integer separation

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following program that convert string integer into integer, but how can i convert to integer if the string contain both alphanumeric?

Here is my code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int convstrg(const char* str) {
  int output = 0;
  char* p = str;
  for (;;) {
    char c = *p++;
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
      break;
      output *= 10;
      output += c - '0';
    } else {
      output = 0;
    }
    return output;
  }
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", convstrg("aaa"));
  return
```

0;
}

when the input is "100" i am getting 100 as output, but when it contains "a201" i am getting empty result, instead it should return 201 and ingore any non numeric char. Thanks

Comment: this is c programming

Comment: If it is c, don't tag c++.

Comment: Are you sure that "a201" contains an 'a' that should be ignored before a decimal value, and is not actually a hexadecimal number in which 'a' is a digit ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton hi when i give an input of "20abc23" it should return just 2023 integer

Comment: I re-formatted your code.  It certainly does not look like you would get `100` with input `"100"`.  Please double check your posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP post has multiple issues

1. `if (c < '0' || c > '9') { break; ... }` is certainly amiss.
2. `char* p = str;` should be `const char* p = str;` to maintain const-ness.
3. `output *= 10; output += c - '0';` need to be located in an `if()` that *includes* digits.
4. `for()` loop needs termination test
5. `return` needs relocation.

..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int convstrg(const char* str) {
  int output = 0;
  // char* p = str;
  const char* p = str;
  // for (;;) {
  for (;*p;) {
    char c = *p++;
    // if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))  {
      // break;
      output *= 10;
      output += c - '0';
    }
    // return output;
  }
  return output;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", convstrg("100"));
  printf("%d\n", convstrg("a201"));
  printf("%d\n", convstrg("20abc23"));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @novavent  Code is now amended to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `break`, put `continue`.

`break` exits out of the loop. `continue` will just have it move on to the next character.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want `return` inside the loop and `else` condition.Taking care of boundaries, this should do the trick

```
#include <stdio.h>
int convstrg(char* str) {
   int output = 0;
   char* p = str;
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;p[i]!='\0';i++) {
      char c = *p++;
      if (c < '0' || c > '9')
          continue;
      output *= 10;
      output += c - '0';
   }   
   return output;
}

int main(){
    char x[] = "1xx2";
    printf("%d\n", convstrg(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error on codepad In function 'convstrg':
Line 5: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode